# putty and browser automation as single script

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webforms, selenium-ide, putty

I have given a scenario of automating putty and Website form.

Putty - Need to run list of  commands in linux and extract an IP at end. and then have to open that IP in web Browser.

Web Browser - In Web browser I need to fill a form. (I will use Selenium to fill form).

Here I want to know, Can I automate both putty and Selenium (to fill web Form) as single Script ??
or any other alternative which can be used to automate both putty and web browser form filling..?

Comment: yes. you can. Use python (or java... or...) and write the script. Not much of a question here...

Comment: @Dmart Thank you. I tried in Java using Selenium (for Browser automation) and Jcraft  (For SSh)  packages.. If any better solution's are accepted..